# AttributeError: 'Eth' object has no attribute 'abi'

Tags: blockchain, python, ganache, django

I am building a web application using django to register phone battery details and it interacts with a smart contract. I am trying to use the decode_log method but I keep getting this error:

> event_data = w3.eth.abi.decode_log(EVENT_ABI, logs[0])
> AttributeError: 'Eth' object has no attribute 'abi'

It is part of the view function:

```
            if logs:
            event_abi = contract.events.BatteryRegistered._get_event_abi()
            event_data = w3.eth.abi.decode_log(EVENT_ABI, logs[0])
            battery_id = event_data['batteryId'].hex()
            request.session['battery_id'] = battery_id
            return redirect('battery_registration_success')
```

this is the view funtion:

```
def battery_registration(request):
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("http://127.0.0.1:7545"))
w3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)
contract = w3.eth.contract(address=CONTRACT_ADDRESS, abi=contract_abi)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = BatteryRegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():  
        manufacturer = request.user.manufacturer
        from_address = "0x6dcA0D94ED15473d0b92cb58D5beBbbFC62CB566"
        watt_hours = int(form.cleaned_data['watt_hours'])
        # Process form data and register battery
        transaction = contract.functions.registerBattery(
            form.cleaned_data['product_name'],
            form.cleaned_data['certification_mark'],
            form.cleaned_data['serial_number'],
            watt_hours,
        ).transact({'from': "0x6dcA0D94ED15473d0b92cb58D5beBbbFC62CB566"})
        transaction_receipt = w3.eth.get_transaction_receipt(transaction)
        logs = w3.eth.get_logs({
            'fromBlock': transaction_receipt['blockNumber'],
            'toBlock': transaction_receipt['blockNumber'],
            'address': CONTRACT_ADDRESS
        })
        if logs:
            event_abi = contract.events.BatteryRegistered._get_event_abi()
            event_data = w3.eth.abi.decode_log(EVENT_ABI, logs[0])
            battery_id = event_data['batteryId'].hex()
            request.session['battery_id'] = battery_id
            return redirect('battery_registration_success')
else:
    form = BatteryRegistrationForm()
return render(request, 'battery_registration.html', {'form': form})
```

I am building it on a local blockchain network, Ganache. It is my first smart contract and first time using django, so can you please help!